# Regex to replace block comment with line comment

Tags: regex

There are tons of examples to do the conversion from C-style line comment to 1-line block comment. But I need to do the opposite: find a regex to replace multi-line block comment with line comments.
From:

```
This text must not be touched
/*
This
is
random
text
*/
This text must not be touched
```

To

```
This text must not be touched
// This
// is
// random
// text
This text must not be touched
```

I was thinking if there's a way to represent "each line" concept in regex, then just add `//`  in front of each line. Something like

```
\/\*\n(?:(.+)\n)+\*\/ -> // $1
```

But the greediness nature of the regex engine makes `$1` just match the last line before `*/`. I know Perl and other languages have some advanced regex features like recursion, but I need to do this in a standard engine. Is there any trick to accomplish this?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm looking for pure regex solution, not involving any programming language. Should be testable on sites like https://regex101.com/.

Comment: What is the environment, in which you can use only standard regular expressions?

Comment: Let's assume Javascript, like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Use `/\/\*([^]*?)\*\//g` to match a comment block then replace each `^` with `//`

Comment: So you want to remove the `/*` `*/` and prepend the `// ` in one match - replace?

Comment: Yes, Add `// ` in front of each line within the original block, in one match replace.

Comment: This is definitely possible in a single regex in Javascript. PCRE may bee able to work but there might be some edge cases of nested comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in a single regex pass in the modern JavaScript engine (and other regex engines supporting infinite length patterns in lookbehinds), you can use

```
/(?<=^(\/)\*(?:(?!^\/\*)[\s\S])*?\r?\n)(?=[\s\S]*?^\*\/)|(?:\r?\n)?(?:^\/\*|^\*\/)/gm
```

Replace with `$1$1`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jDIcWR/2).

**Details**

- `(?<=^(\/)\*(?:(?!^\/\*)[\s\S])*?\r?\n)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `^(\/)\*` - `/*` substring at the start of a line (with `/` captured into Group 1)
  - `(?:(?!^\/\*)[\s\S])*?` - any char, zero or more occurrences, as few as possible, not starting a `/*` char sequence that appears at the start of a line
  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF ending
- `(?=[\s\S]*?^\*\/)` - a positive lookahead that requires any 0 or more chars as few as possible followed with `*/` at the start of a line, immediately to the right of the current location
- `|` - or
- `(?:\r?\n)?` - an optional CRLF or LF linebreak
- `(?:^\/\*|^\*\/)` - and then either `/*` or `*/` at the start of a line.

Comment: So you use the capturing group in the lookbehind to be the replacement, because if you use `//` literally you would get `//` in the replacement for every match which is too much. And due to the alternation, group 1 can be empty so there is no replacement right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Correct, the solution is tricky, the alternation does not let hardcode the replacement pattern. So, more a hack for this concrete scenario.

Comment: I was playing around to see how to solve it, but this is awesome. One technique to remember :-) ++

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So if instead we need to prefix something like `#/` or `@@`, this trick won't work, right? We are just lucky then. BTW, the first line in Details is a typo (lookbehind)?

Comment: Problem: if there are `/*` inside the block comment, they will be replaced as well.

Comment: @CrendKing You can't use JS regex to match nested structures. So, no nested comment support.

Comment: I was talking about something like `/* \n http://*/* \n */ -> // http://*/*`. Since there is no `*/` inside, I don't think it is exactly "nested". Can you modify the regex to only match `^\/\*` and `^\*\/`?

Comment: @CrendKing [Like this](https://regex101.com/r/jDIcWR/2)?

Answer (score 1):

As usual in such cases, two regular expressions—the second applied to the matches of the first—can do what one cannot achieve.

```js
const txt = `This text must not be touched
/*
This
is
random
text
*/
This text must not be touched`;

const to1line = str => str.replace(
    /\/\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*\//gs,
    (_, comment) => comment.replace( /^/mg, '//')
);
console.log( to1line( txt ));
```

Comment: When I say Javascript, I meant the Javascript style regex. No code is allowed. Can you link a testable https://regex101.com/ instance?

Comment: I do not think that it can be done with one regular expression, due to variable number of lines, and therefore captures, in a multi-line comment.
Even if somebody can, I think he shouldn't.

Comment: I can accept answer like "it is not possible because ..." if you are sure about that. You can keep the existing Javascript code here in case other people can use a code-based solution.

Comment: Wait some time, perhaps somebody will find a way.